Total energy and time derivative of it in general relativity
I'm studying general relativity through Sean Caroll's book (An introduction to gr;  Spacetime and geometry which must be quite similar to its notes)
It defines total energy as: $$E_T=\int_\sum J^\mu_Tn_\mu\sqrt{\gamma}d^3x$$ where $\sum$ is a spacelike hypersurface, $\gamma$ the induced metric and $n$ a normal vector to $\sum$. And $J$ is the current constructed with a timelike killing vector: $$J^\mu_T=K_\eta T^{\mu\eta}.$$
This definition comes from: $E_T=\int_M\nabla\overline{J}=\int_\sum(*\overline{J})$ (Stoke's theorem), doesn't it? Which is the motivation for it?
The time variation of energy can be computed as  $\partial_tE_T=\int_\sum(\partial_t*\overline{J})$ and $\partial_t$ will act as a killing vector, wouldnt it?
Im quite newbie to GR, thanks!
